# No fill where text overlaps in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have a word where one object (letter) meets with another. You can see some white part at the junction of the letters "L" and "A". It is transparent just like it has been cut but every single letter should be filled.

How can totally fill the word with one color?

[image: Here is an example.]

Comment: Is that actual type or paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by incorrect path directions (either in live type<sup>*</sup> or a compound path).

You can change the direction of a path through the Attributes panel. Select the problem path, set it to use a "Non-Zero Winding Fill Rule" (the left of the far right icons) and use the two middle icons to reverse the path direction. If there are counters (i.e. the hole in the "O" in the following example), you will need to reverse the direction of that path too...

[image]

---

<sup>*</sup>  If this is live type then it is a sure sign of a badly created font. You should probably use a more reliable font if you're using it for any length of text (or if you're only using few enough characters to manually fix then convert the type to outlines).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the glyphs are type which has been converted to outlines, they are part of a *compound shape* in all likelihood.

An easy fix is to separate the L from the compound shape.

- Select the L using the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow)
- Choose `Edit > Cut` from the menu
- Choose `Edit > Paste in Front` from the menu

The L will then be a separate shape and will overlap the A without creating a counter or hole.

If you then what them to all be one compound shape again, select all the letters and click the `Merge` or `Unite` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.