# Illustrator Compound path not working on full shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I'm an enthousiast graphic designer. I usually like to play with multiple tools and textures to make clothing for my company.

I'm trying to use Compound path with my logo and a vectorised texture but it looks like he tool is "forgetting" a couple of paths (the hook, F, Y, C and line under CO).[image]

Would anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Which paths are forgotten?

Comment: The hook, the F, Y, C and the line under the CO were not affected by the action.

Comment: Are those paths actually a part of the compound path after the operation and the problem is just the visual output, or are they not being included in the compound path at all?

Comment: group the elements then try the action on them

Comment: Before use tha clipping mask... Make sure is all ungoruped, so ungroup everything (the clipping mask path does not support a group of paths, just paths and compound paths). Use ctrl+shift+G a couple of times, then make all a compound path using Ctrl+8. Send it to front: Ctrl + shift + ]. Select the compound path and the texture and Ctrl + 7.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the paths are actually a part of the compound path, it's probably caused by incorrect path directions and fill rules.

See my answer to [No fill where text overlaps in Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/98090/52050).

Select only the problem paths (with the Direct Selection Tool) and use the Attributes panel to change the fill rule (right buttons) and path direction (middle buttons).

An example. The "D" here has a reversed path direction:

[image]

After swapping the path direction on the "D" paths:

[image]

Comment: CAI, thank you. Have had this issue many times and just always remade the shape from scratch. This worked first time for a very complex shape. Life saver.